# How would I get a value between 0 and 1 depending on positive/negative input?

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to generate a number between 0 and 1 (used for opacity) that accurately reflects numbers on this scale:

-249.76684980273333
AND
249.76684980273333

for instance, -249.76684980273333 would be 0.00, and 249.76684980273333 would be 1.00

Comment: Comments purged. Advice for future reviewers: If you can't be civil, take it somewhere else.

Answer (score 10):

Just do

```
x / (2.0*M) + 0.5
```

where `M = 249.76684980273333`

---

To solve this kind of problem, you want to find a formula describing a particular linear equation.  The equation will map your 'big' numbers (the input `x`) into the numbers between 0-1 (the output `y`).

You can use the formula for a line from two points:

[image]

In your case, since you've said "-249.76684980273333 would be 0.00, and 249.76684980273333 would be 1.00", then it should be clear that two different points lying on the line you're interested in are:

```
(x1, y1) = -249.76684980273333, 0.00
(x2, y2) = 249.76684980273333, 1.00
```

Substitute these into the formula, and solve it in the form of a line like `y = m*x + b`, and from this you can easily write your algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to also put limits on the value of *x* to ensure the result is in the correct range and doen't go out of bounds, e.g. something like `(x > M)? 1 : (x < -M)? 0 : x / (2.0*M) + 0.5;`.

Answer (score 6):

```
function scale(min, max, value) {
    return value/(max-min) + min
}
```

min = the minimum of your range, in your example, -249.76684980273333
max = the maximum of your range, in your example, 249.76684980273333
value = the value you are testing

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
y = (x+249.76684980273333)/(2*249.76684980273333);
```